# How to find out if a Type implements an interface in Java?

Tags: java, types, interface, casting

This seems to be very easy, but I was not able to solve it for days now... I must be too stupid, and so I hope to get some help here (couldn't find the answer though).

I simply want to know if a given Type implements some interface. For example, does type X implement the `Serializable` interface? It should give `true` for types X like `JComponent.class`, and false for `Thread.class`.

Or, stated differently, can an object of type X be cast to the given interface?

I tried `instanceof` and `isAssignableFrom`, but nothing seems to work.

**EDIT:**

Ok, maybe I really was too stupid :-( I have tried the following:

This code does not compile:

```
    Type t1 = JComponent.class;
    Type t2 = Thread.class;
    Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(t1);
    Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(t2);
```

This code yields true for both t1 and t2 (which makes sense, of course):

```
    Type t1 = JComponent.class;
    Type t2 = Thread.class;
    Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(t1.getClass());
    Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(t2.getClass());
```

(And similar things with instanceOf do not work either.)

But what DOES seem to work is this:

```
    Type t1 = JComponent.class;
    Type t2 = Thread.class;
    Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom((Class<?>) t1);
    Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom((Class<?>) t2);
```

As a Type that implements an interface should always be a Class (right?), the cast should work in all cases... (**EDIT**: There is an even simpler solution - I used the wrong method for retreiving the constructor parameters (getGenericParameterTypes); using just getParameterTypes gives a list of Class objects rather than Type objects and there is no problem at all.)

Thank you for the very quick help!

Lukas

Comment: Why didn't `instanceof` and `isAssignableFrom()` work? From what I know they *should* work. Can you add more detail?

Comment: `instanceof` and `isAssignableFrom` should both work. What error are you getting? Can you put in more details?

Comment: If a type implements an interface, you can access access access this methods in your code, so this is what compiler knows when compiles your program, hence for me it's no sence of finding this out during runtime. Why do you need to check this?

Comment: yeah ok, I should have been more specific - I believe, the main issue is that I have a Type object, not a Class to test. For example, this works fine:

        Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(JComponent.class);
        Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(Thread.class);

Comment: I want to construct an object by accessing its constructor via reflections. I want to know at runtime if a given type matches the parameter type, so i can send the respective object to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, both `instanceof` and `isAssignablefrom()` work. Try the following example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // it is serializable
System.out.println(list instanceof Serializable); // should print true
System.out.println(Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(list.getClass())); // should print true too
```

EDIT

Concerning to the second question. Yes, you can use both techniques to check whether the object can be cast.

Comment: Ok, but what if I don't have access to an object of the list type (or whatever). All I have is a list of types given by the c.getGenericParameterTypes() method of a Constructor c, and I want to find out, if one of them implements the List interface (for instance).

Comment: Please try to write code and if it does not work post it here and ask specific question.

Answer (score 0):

`object` `instanceof` `object_interface` will yield true